# Activemq destination renaming

Tags: activemq-classic

Is it possible to rename a destination (Queue or Topic) in Activemq ? If yes, is it possible without losing the messages it contains before renaming ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

Why don't you create a new one, then just copy all messages to the new queue?
This can be done via the JMX interface or by just moving the messages in code.